# Добавление новых линий на экран

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

```
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  if(pressPrint == true)
  {
      x1 = ui->x1Pos->value(),
      y1 = ui->y1Pos->value(),
      x2 = ui->x2Pos->value(),
      y2 = ui->y2Pos->value();

      QPainter painter(this);
      painter.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
      update();
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  x1vector.push_back(ui->x1Pos->value());
  x2vector.push_back(ui->x2Pos->value());
  y1vector.push_back(ui->y1Pos->value());
  y2vector.push_back(ui->y2Pos->value());
}
```

Есть код рисующий  линию по координатам мышки и передающий `x1,x2,y1,y2` в вектора, необходимо, чтобы при создании следующей линии предыдущая оставалась на экране.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать `QGraphicsScene` и метод `addItem`.

```
    x1 = ui->x1Pos->value(),
    y1 = ui->y1Pos->value(),
    x2 = ui->x2Pos->value(),
    y2 = ui->y2Pos->value();
    QLine line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    scene->addLine(line);
```

Так же можно воспользоваться `QPainterPath`.

```
    // QPainterPath, например, объявленный в классе
    m_path;
    // Предполагаю, что точка x1,y1 уже была когда-то отрисована. Или можно попробовать `translate(x1,y1)`
    m_path.lineTo(QPointF(x2, y2));
    painter.drawPath(m_path);
```

Comment: ИМХО, хороший совет, но не мешало бы добавить пример

Answer (score 1):

Хм, можно проще. Надо завести тип для хранения линии (Можно еще завести тип для хранения точки):

```
struct Line {
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int y1;
    int y2;
}
```

Далее, вы используете странные вектора точек - предлагаю заменить их на один массив линий:

```
QList<Line> lines;
```

Теперь ваш код будет выглядеть проще:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    // Добавляем очередную линию
    lines.push_back({
        ui->x1Pos->value(),
        ui->x2Pos->value(),
        ui->y1Pos->value(),
        ui->y2Pos->value()
    }
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    if (pressPrint) {  

        QPainter painter(this);
        // Рисуем все линии
        for(int i = 0; i < lines.count(); i++) {        
            Line line = lines[i];
            painter.drawLine(
                line.x1, line.y1, 
                line.x2, line.y2
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Даже есть класс такой - QLine

Comment: @eugesh да, много чего есть, но изобретение небольшого велосипеда позволяет понять суть процессов.